# Is there any way to extend a legacy .net 4 website with .net Core without porting everything?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a fairly large legacy website based on .NET 4.72 / ASP.NET MVC. I'm planning to add some more content and would like to use Blazor for that if any possible. From a user's viewpoint, the new content should integrate seamlessly into the legacy site.

However, porting the entire project to .NET would take a lot of effort, probably too much just to use the new frameworks.

Is there any trick I could use to mix both so that I only have to port some shared libraries, but not the old ASP.NET project? For instance by using virtual directory for the new project and making sure that both use compatible authentication providers and the same data source?

Thanks,

Adrian

Comment: Port your shared libraries to .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: Host the ASP.NET and ASP.NET Core/Blazor apps separately, and then set up a reverse proxy in front to manipulate URLs.

Comment: @Ian Kemp: Yes, that's what I was going to do. What I would like to know is how I can avoid having to port the website project as well.

Comment: @LexLi: Excellent idea! It seems like an easy solution. Thanks!